# Not return json-parameter on submit() in extjs 3.4

Tags: extjs

html code:

```
          loadfile.getForm().submit({
                        url: 'http://host/test/file-upload.php?path='+r.get('dtp'),
                        waitMsg: 'Сохранение фотографии...',
                        success: function(loadfile, o){
                            Ext.Msg.alert('Success', o.result.msg);
                        }
               });
```

file-upload.php:

```
      <?php
         $uploaddir = '/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/test/upload/'.$_GET["path"];
         if (!is_dir($uploaddir))
           {
             mkdir($uploaddir, 0777);
           }
         $uploaddir.='/';
         if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploaddir.$_FILES['userfile']['name']))
          {
           echo '{"success": true, "msg": "урааааааааааааа"}';
          } else {
           echo '{"success": false, "msg": "Файл не сохранён!"}';
          }
      ?>
```

i get error:

```
    Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'msg' of undefined
```

if set in html this:

```
  Ext.Msg.alert('Success', 'Success...');
```

all its work, but always was success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was in html start on tomcat6 but PHP start on apache. When i start PHP on tomcat6 all it work.